# SQL: How to Get The Average of Each Column Using Group By

Tags: sql, postgresql, presto

I have a table with columns 1, 2, 3, ... 200 and an id column I'm grouping by. This is to be done in Presto.

I could do something like this:

```
SELECT id, AVG(col_1), AVG(col_2), AVG(col_3), ..., AVG(col_200) FROM 
table
GROUP BY id
```

But that would be extremely laborious to write out each column name. Is there a more convenient syntax to accomplish this?

Comment: Use the metadata to construct the columns.  Usually having such repeated columns is an issue anyway -- they should be in another table or array.

Comment: How are you issuing the queries? Manually, or from some other programming environment?